# How to make CMD say something?

Tags: cmd

I need to create a .cmd file, and when I execute it, opens up cmd and then shows whatever I typed in the file. Like

(Of course this is fake)

Scanning.....c:/windows
Scanning.....c:/
Scanning.....Ports

etc,so it says whatever I want.

Also, is there a way to have a interval of when it says something?

Like:

Scanning.....
(5secs after)
Scanning....

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

```
echo textGoesHere
```

or

```
echo "Hey look, text"
```

will output the text.

```
pause
```

will wait for the user to press a key and prompt with "press any key to continue".

```
sleep 5
```

will pause for 5 seconds.

However, as of Windows Vista, sleep seems to no longer be included in the default set of commands.  Supposedly this: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD&displaylang=en contains the sleep.exe file you'd need to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to ping the localhost for 20 seconds:

```
@echo Off
@echo "Scanning.... C:\Windows"   
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 20 > nul
@echo "Scanning.... Ports"

pause
```

Comment: A hack, yes, but should work in all versions of Windows (assuming TCP/IP support is installed).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, to create a .cmd/.bat file(AKA Batch file) to say something

We use `echo` and the syntax is `echo YOURTEXT`Abd if you want to have spaces in between: `echo"YOUR TEXT"` as simple as that. And to add a blank line:`echo.` (Yup, add the dot without space)

Now for the delay
I recommend the `timeout` command, and the syntax is: `timeout /t "your time in seconds without quotation marks"`
There are also some additional options you can add:
If you don't want the command to display the text "Waiting for * seconds, press a key to continue" then add `>nul` at the end if all options.
And if you don't want to allow someone to press any key to continue, use the option `/nobreak` after `/t` and before `>nul` if you're using `>nul`

And now for more stuff

You can change the title of the file by using `title`, the syntax is `title "Titile you want to change to with quotations if you want spaces"`

You can also actually change the foreground and background colour , for instructions, type `color/?` into **Command Prompt**

You can actually don't let the batch file display "C:\Users\Yourname>" or anything like that infront of any command by using `@echo off` at the first sentence in the whole batch file.

And you can also use `pause` to pause the file from running any further until any key is pressed. And if you don't want it to display "Press any key to continue" you can also add `>nul` at the back.

To clear the whole page: `cls`

Ok, enough said, now here is an example file:

`Color 02
Title Windows Scanner
Echo.
Echo =====================
Echo    Windows Scanner Pro
Echo              v2.0 BETA
Echo =====================
Echo.
Echo Press any key to start Basic Scan
Pause>nul
Cls
Echo =====================
Echo    Windows Scanner Pro
Echo              v2.0 BETA
Echo =====================
Echo.
Echo Starting Scan...
Timeout /t 5 /nobreak>nul
Echo.
Echo SCAN STARTED
Timeout /t 8 /nobreak>nul
Echo ...
Timeout /t 3 /nobreak>nul
Echo ...
Timeout /t 6/nobreak>nul
Cls
Echo =====================
Echo    Windows Scanner Pro
Echo              v2.0 BETA
Echo =====================
Echo.
Echo SCAN RESULTS:
Echo Nothing found
Echo.
Pause
Echo THANKS FOR USING OUR SERVICE
Echo.
Pause
Cls
Echo ====================
Echo    Windows Scanner Pro
Echo              v2.0 BETA
Echo =====================
Echo.
Echo Bye!
Echo.
Echo Press any key to exit
Pause>nul
Exit`

That's just an example(And is not a real scan), you can edit and do more stuff with it, you can even ask the user to input the type of scan they want! ( Search google it ask it again or contact me)

Answer (score 1):

use `echo` command.

For delaying:

failed to test but try to use `sleep` command.

Comment: Your bat file : echo "test first echo" sleep 10 echo "test second"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a spinning bar you can also take the script from my site [here](http://www.sysstem.at/2012/10/windows-commandline-batch-loading-function/)

as this link appears down here is what you can do.
Please see the link (if it gets online ever again) what it is about the backline. (it contains 79 0x09 characters which could not be typed in by an ordinary notepad)

```
    @echo off

:Scan
echo Start Scan
scan.exe parameter
:Scanloop
tasklist | find>nul "PING.EXE" & call :Spinner Scanning... || goto:end
goto Scanloop

:end
cls
echo This is the end
pause>nul

rem ***************************************
rem * Spinner
rem ***************************************
:Spinner
set backline=
<nul (set/p z=[\] %*)
<nul (set/p z=%backline%)
ping>nul localhost -n 1
<nul (set/p z=[^|] %*)
<nul (set/p z=%backline%)
ping>nul localhost -n 1
<nul (set/p z=[/] %*)
<nul (set/p z=%backline%)
ping>nul localhost -n 1
<nul (set/p z=[-] %*)
<nul (set/p z=%backline%)
ping>nul localhost -n 1
goto :EOF
```

This would be the script.

```
ping>nul -n 2 localhost
```

waits ca. 1 second and

```
ping>nul -n 3 localhost
```

waits ca 2 seconds. It is not as precise as sleep, but takes less ressources.

Comment: Your edit is a bit better, as it does at least now seem as though you are answering the question asked. However, your answer does not work (the comment in question returns immediately), and by the title, your link does not seem to address the question. (the site seems to be dead, too, btw)